# Git reflog throws syntax error in Windows

Tags: git

I'm using Git-1.8.1.2-preview20130201 in Windows. When I try running `git reflog` I get the following error:

```
1 > git reflog
C:/Program Files (x86)/Git/bin/pg: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `('
C:/Program Files (x86)/Git/bin/pg: -c: line 0: `C:/Program Files (x86)/Git/bin/pg'
```

Has anyone seen this? I don't even see a "pg" binary under C:/Program Files (x86)/Git/bin/.

Comment: `pg` seems to be a pager (just discovered on my linux system) and in my opinion the error came from the path that contains a `(` (probably the script doesn't escape it). Try to set the `--no-pager` option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up doing the following as per https://superuser.com/questions/366930/how-do-i-get-the-git-pager-to-act-normal-less-leaves-output-on-the-screen-when:

```
git config --global core.pager 'less -+$LESS -R'
```

Then, when done, I hit 'q' to quit the pager.

Answer (score 2):

It seems you have the environment variable `PAGER` or `GIT_PAGER` set to `C:/Program Files (x86)/Git/bin/pg`. You need to escaped brackets and the spaces in it like this:

```
C:/Program\ Files\ \(x86\)/Git/bin/pg
```

An easy way to test this is using this command:

```
GIT_PAGER="C:/Program\ Files\ \(x86\)/Git/bin/pg" git reflog
```

Alternatively, you could use the `--no-pager` flag as @gipi suggested in a comment, like this:

```
git --no-pager reflog
```

Comment: Thanks janos, where can I set this environment variable in order to automatically apply it for every instance of git-bash?

Comment: You can set either as 1. user environment variable, 2. system environment variable, or 3. in `~/.profile`